# Does anyone know if I can use Siri to make a phone call using Google Voice?

Tags: iphone, siri, google-voice

Either that or place a call with the phone app using my Google Voice number.

I ported my main number out to Google Voice. I want to be able to make hands-free phone calls from my main phone number on Google Voice, instead of the random phone number I have assigned to my iPhone. Using "Hey Siri" opens the iPhone app, so does Google Assistant.

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Ask Different! :)  I hope you come to find this site has a lot to offer! In case you haven't already, it's worth taking the time to read the [tour](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tour). All the best with your question.

Comment: has the answer stayed the same since iOS 7?  If so, I would consider this to be a duplicate.  If not, then no duplicate (however, as I am not a mod, my opinion doesn't truly count)

Answer (score 0):

This depends on Google integrating their app with Siri as since iOS 10, developers can make their apps work with Siri using Siri Kit. So it’s up to a Google to do it, in the meantime, this isn’t possible.